# MAGENTO - OBSERVER to copy customerTAXVAT code into VAT_ID

Tags: php, magento, observers

As you know MAgento has2 version of VAT field in the customer master
TAXVAT and VAT_ID (the second one is the field into the custoemr adress attributes)

I want to create an observer to copy TAXVAT into VAT_ID everytime i save a customer and the TAXVAT is not blank.

Code looks like this:

Config.xml:

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Fontis_Customer>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </Fontis_Customer>
</modules>
<global>
    <events>
        <customer_save_before>
            <observers>
                <fontis_customer_save_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Fontis_Customer_Model_Customer_Observer</class>
                    <method>customer_save_before</method>
                </fontis_customer_save_observer>
            </observers>
        </customer_save_before>
    </events>
</global>
```

And this is the observer: observer.php:

```
<?php
class Fontis_Customer_Model_Customer_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    /*
     * observer for the customer saved event
     */
public function customer_save_before( $observer )
{
    try {
        $customer = $observer->getCustomer();

        if( $customer->getData('taxvat') !== '' ) {
            $customer->setData( 'vat_id', $customer->getData('taxvat') ); // Copy taxvat into vat_id
        } else {}
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        Mage::log( "customer_save_before observer failed: " . $e->getMessage() );
    }
}
}

?>
```

Could you please help? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Try use `$customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();`

Comment: I tried with this change but it does not work.

I think there is something wrong with the variables and the way i'm calling them...not sure how to retrieve taxvat, and not sure how to set vat_id since it is part of customer adress attributes.